# node and npm setup using the zip file

Tags: node.js

I am trying to setup node by downloading the .zip file from https://nodejs.org/en/download/ and extracting to a folder instead of using the .exe installation file.
Following are the steps I have followed, but once I install the angular cli the npm folder itself is getting deleted

1. I downloaded the zip version of node and extracted to my local folder D:\software\node\node-v16.17.0-win-x64
   It had the npm folder D:\software\node\node-v16.17.0-win-x64\npm
2. Install angular cli using "D:\software\node\node-v16.17.0-win-x64\npm install @angular/cli", it deleted the npm folder D:\software\node\node-v16.17.0-win-x64\npm, and now npm is not working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why not use the msi installer?

Comment: I do not have the admin privilege